# cant have expected result; find the names of sailors who have reserved all boats called Interlake

Tags: sql-server

these are the 3 tables(sailors , boats , reserves) and i want to know the sailors who reserved both interlake boats(101,102) .The bID should be calculated by the computer

```
`select * from sailors
 where sid in(select sid from reserves
  inner join boats on reserves.bid = boats.bid
  where boats.bname='Interlake')`
```

a link to see the image of tables  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfHpH.png
or link to pdf form http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~avaisman/csc343summer/tutorials/Tutorial_5.pdf

result = dustin luber horatio
expected = dustin horation
thanks for ur help

Comment: what have you tried?  this is homework, you're supposed to be learning how to answer these questions yourself.

Comment: @Beth Are you saying "This question does not show any research effort", as in the tooltip for the downvote button? Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

**Explanation**

1. Know the number of boats where name = interlake using cte report
2. Find all the sailors that reserved the boat with name interlake using summary cte
3. Find all sailors who reserved all the boats

Query

```
declare @boat varchar(50) = 'Interlake'

;with report as (
 select bname,count(*) as [Count]
 from boats b  
 where b.bname=@boat
 group by b.bname
), summary as(
  select s.sname, b.bname, count(*) as [Count]
  from sailors s
  inner join reserves r on r.sid = s.sid
  inner join boats b on b.bid = r.bid
  where b.bname=@boat
  group by s.sname,b.bname
)

select s.*
from  summary s
inner join report r on r.bname = s.bname and r.[Count] = s.[Count]
```

Here a working [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86c2d/1)

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL will build temp table variables, populate them and then use joins to show you which sailors have reserved the InterLake boats.

--Build sailors temp table variable and insert test data

```
declare @sailors table
([sid]  int
,[name] varchar(50))
insert into @sailors
([sid],[name])
values
(1,'Sailor One'),
(2,'Sailor Two'),
(3,'Sailor Three')
```

--Build boats temp table variable and insert test data

```
declare @boats table
(bid    int
,[name] varchar(50))
insert into @boats
(bid,[name])
values
(1,'10 foot John Boat'),
(2,'14 foot John Boat'),
(3,'18 foot Ski Boat'),
(4,'Interlake')
```

--Build reserves temp table variable and insert test data

```
declare @reserves table
(rid    int
,[sid]  int
,bid    int)
insert into @reserves
(rid,[sid],bid)
values
(1, 1, 4),
(2, 3, 1),
(3, 2, 4)
```

--Query to select which sailors have reserved Interlake boats

```
select      s.name as Sailor
            ,b.name as Boat
from        @sailors s
inner join  @reserves r on r.[sid] = s.[sid]
inner join  @boats b on b.bid = r.bid
where       b.name = 'InterLake'
```

--Results

```
Sailor      Boat
Sailor One  Interlake
Sailor Two  Interlake
```

Comment: Given op's data sample, you query will return the same results as op's. Your query doesn't differentiate those who have reserved ONLY both. Your query will return results those who have rented one or the other or both.

Comment: My query will return only the sailors that rented the Interlake boat. You say 
 "Your query will return results those who have rented one or the other or both"........I don't understand your response, one or the other or both? Please explain.....

Answer (score 0):

First we will join the two tables on where sailors sid matches reserves sid AND where the bid is 101 or 102, because that is what `Interlake`'s bid is. If you want to do by `where bname = interlake`, you will join boats into reserves. This is something you have already done in your original query using `inner join`. I choose to use left:

```
select s.*
from sailors s
left join reserves r on r.sid = s.sid
where r.bid in (101, 102)
```

Now that I have everyone who has reserved the boats 101 or 102. I want to filter out those who only have both. In this case, I want to query from my filtered results. I decided to use a derived table, but you can use a cte alternatively.

Something like:

```
select *
from
(select s.*
from sailors s
left join reserves r on r.sid = s.sid
where r.bid in (101, 102)) t1 --t1 is the alias
```

But I don't want everything from this filtered table. I want the names.

```
select sname
from
(select s.*
from sailors s
left join reserves r on r.sid = s.sid
where r.bid in (101, 102)) t1
```

But I only want the names of those who have rented both 101 and 102. In this case if I count by the name, that means you could have only rented both if your count is GREATER than 1:

```
select sname --select the column of names I want
       ,count(sname) as total --here's the count of names, completely optional
from 
(select s.*
from sailors s
left join reserves r on r.sid = s.sid
where r.bid in (101, 102)) t1
group by sname --anything you use an aggregation you'll need to likely group by something
having count(sname)  > 1 --my filter after I group my names
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/TMW34692) sample you can play with.

Comment: We shall not input the bid number e.g "where r.bid in (**101**, **102**)) t1" .the system shall find the bid through the query .The query should search all bid where the bname = interlake , then find the all sid who reserves boats' bid where bname=interlake

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.SID,S.SNAME,S.RATING,S.AGE
FROM  SAILORS S,RESERVES R,BOATS B 
WHERE  S.SID=R.SID AND  R.BID=B.BID
AND NOT EXISTS
          ((SELECT  B.BID
             FROM  BOATS B WHERE B.BNAME NOT LIKE '%INTERLAKE%')
            EXCEPT
             (SELECT  R.BID
              FROM  RESERVES R
              WHERE  R.SID=S.SID))
```